# PHP/MYSQL Import Contacts

Tags: php, import, contacts

I would like to import contacts from hotmail, gmail etc. for a social website.  Openinviter seems to require server installation privileges which my host does not grant me.  Does anyone know of a library or other file for pulling in contacts that I could just place in a directory.  Or a tutorial or guidance for roll your own?  Alternatively, can anyone suggest a way through tutorial or script to import contacts from a csv or delimited file?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching data from CSV to MySQL is pretty common and so you can get a lot of examples, classes ready to use and best practises just googling a little bit. Even MySQL has its own way of doing that via 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'.

I don't know any other solution like OpenInviter that does not require some use of filesystem and installation of packages. :/

Comment: Despite the above people wanting to close this, this is a really important question for people who want to get contacts.  Thanks for taking a shot at it.